# SQL problem with selection after joining groups

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a two tables:

**Table Faculty:**

```
(facultyName varchar(1000),foundationYear int,PRIMARY KEY(facultyName))
```

and **Table Groups**

```
(groupId int,facultyName varchar(10),groupNumber int,groupYear int, leaderStudentId int,PRIMARY KEY(groupId))
```

I want to select all faculties which has at least two groups which groupYears are 2008.

This is my code

```
create table Students(studentId int, firstName varchar(10),lastName varchar[10],avgMark int,gender bool ,PRIMARY KEY(studentId));
create table Faculty (facultyName varchar(1000),foundationYear int,PRIMARY KEY(facultyName));
create table Groups (groupId int,facultyName varchar(10),groupNumber int,groupYear int, leaderStudentId int,PRIMARY KEY(groupId));
create table StudentsInGroup (studentId int,groupId int,PRIMARY KEY (studentId,groupId));
insert into Students values(1,"Kajik","Hakobyan",1900,1);
insert into Faculty values("kirarakan",1987);
insert into Faculty values("kirarakan1",1987);
insert into Faculty values("kirarakan2",1987);
insert into Groups values(1,"kirarakan",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(2,"kirarakan",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(3,"kirarakan",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(4,"kirarakan1",100,2007,1);
insert into Groups values(5,"kirarakan2",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(6,"kirarakan2",100,2008,1);
SELECT * FROM FACULTY;
SELECT * FROM GROUPS;
SELECT Faculty.facultyName,Faculty.foundationYear
FROM
(
Groups as A
join
Groups as B
on ( A.groupId <> B.groupId AND A.facultyName = B.facultyName And A.groupYear = 2008 AND B.groupYear = 2008  )
)
join
Faculty
on (A.facultyName = Faculty.facultyName)
;
```

But I get "kirarakan" 6 times, and I know why I get this, but I don't know hot to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @Qajik Hakobyan, what database do you use ? Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Hi @Qajik Hakobyan is table Students of any use for this example ? Thanks!

Comment: @forpas I want to see only one facultyName and facultyYear

Comment: What facultyNames should you see for this sample data?

Comment: @forpas  I should see only kirarakan and kirarakan2 , each of them once

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the table `Groups`, so `group by facultyName` and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select facultyName 
from Groups
where groupYear = 2008
group by facultyName
having count(distinct groupId) >= 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8sUJmZ5Tsi1hRK6uwfZM9h/2).
Results:

```
| facultyName |
| ----------- |
| kirarakan   |
| kirarakan2  |
```

Comment: Thanks I found the answer in other way, intersecting the Selecting table with Faculty Table.

Comment: Why? Is it simpler to select from 2 tables and intersect?

Comment: @Qajik Hakobyan post the answer here so others can see it. Maybe you will help someone... Also, if this answer from forpas helped you give him vote up.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Students(studentId int, firstName varchar[10],lastName varchar[10],avgMark int,gender bool ,PRIMARY KEY(studentId));
create table Faculty (facultyName varchar[1000],foundationYear int,PRIMARY KEY(facultyName));
create table Groups (groupId int,facultyName varchar[10],groupNumber int,groupYear int, leaderStudentId int,PRIMARY KEY(groupId));
create table StudentsInGroup (studentId int,groupId int,PRIMARY KEY (studentId,groupId));
insert into Students values(1,"Kajik","Hakobyan",1900,1);
insert into Faculty values("kirarakan",1987);
insert into Faculty values("kirarakan1",1987);
insert into Faculty values("kirarakan2",1987);
insert into Groups values(1,"kirarakan",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(2,"kirarakan",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(3,"kirarakan",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(4,"kirarakan1",100,2007,1);
insert into Groups values(5,"kirarakan2",100,2008,1);
insert into Groups values(6,"kirarakan2",100,2008,1);
SELECT * FROM FACULTY;
SELECT * FROM GROUPS;
Select *
From
Faculty
INTERSECT
SELECT Faculty.facultyName,Faculty.foundationYear
FROM
Faculty 
join
Groups as A
on (Faculty.facultyName = A.facultyName)
join
Groups as B
on ( A.groupId <> B.groupId AND A.facultyName = B.facultyName AND A.groupYear = 2008 AND B.groupYear= 2008)
;
```